# extract array values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi in php I want to extract a array values into new array, with below logic

old array

```
index|value
0=23
1=34
2=45
3=56
4=56
5=78
6=45
7=67
8=56
9=45
```

I want new array stores index values from old one in such series: 0,1,4,5,8,9... so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a "take two, drop two" sequence, this will do it;

```
$input = array(23, 34, 45, 56, 56, 78, 45, 67, 56, 45);
$output = array();

$count = count($input);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $output[$i] = $input[$i];
  if($i % 4 == 1)
    $i += 2;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I will answer as best as I can.

To get a new array with just the values from the original array you can use [`array_values()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

For an array of just the keys you would use [`array_keys()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

To order the array by its values you would use [`asort()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Then to get the array values ordered, but with sequential keys you would use:

```
$array = array(53,23,43);
sort($array);
```

See the [`sort()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just as an exercise, a solution that leverages on [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)

```
class stripes extends ArrayIterator {
    private $partial, $step;

    public function __construct($array, $step) {
        parent::__construct($array);
        $this->step = $step;
        $this->partial=0;
    }

    public function next() {
        $this->partial++;
        if ($this->partial >=$this->step) {
            for($step=$this->step;$step;$step--)
                parent::next();
            $this->partial=0;
        }
        parent::next();
    }
}
```

It has a quite simple usage:

```
$input = array(23,24,45,56,56,78,45,67,56,45);
$iterator = new stripes($input,2);
$result = iterator_to_array($iterator)
```

In `$result` you have the array you need. You can change 
the size of the stripes just changing the second parameter 
of the stripes constructor without polluting your *live code
space*.

References:

[ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php)
[iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)